# paypal: ipn script is activated on refund

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I use paypal ipn and the ipn script is activated when a paypal refund is done

how can I tell in paypal ipn that it's a refund and treat it differently?

Answer (score 2):

payment_status=Refunded

See page 48 here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/ipnguide.pdf

---

2019 edit, current link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#transaction-and-notification-related-variables

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_POST["payment_status"] == "Refunded"){
    //it's a refund
}
```

Note there are other payment statuses too, like Completed (for a sale) and Reversed (for when the buyer makes a complaint).